# How to create sequelize nested for [Op.ne] and [Op.and]?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to create sequelize nested for [Op.ne] and [Op.and]?

```
[Op.and]:[
    {
      [Op.ne]: [
        { status: 'Drop'},
        { '$User.hasDuplicate$': 0}
      ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What was the original purpose?

Comment: I just want get all data from my table Record except for the status Drop and has User(table) column hasduplicate 0

Comment: Haven't done it by myself but accordingly to [doc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#examples-with-opnot) you can omit `[Op.and]` operator